# Frequent visits to the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration, student-visa, uk-visa, uk-visitor-visa

I would like to apply for a student visa in UK. Unfortunately, I've been to UK on 2018, 2019 & 2022 for 180 days. I need to provide 3 recent details previously in UK. Will this matter affect my application or maybe my non-visa visit could be banned?

Comment: Student visas are assessed on different criteria to visits. The frequency and length of your previous visits should not typically make any difference, unless you overstayed or otherwise breached UK immigration rules

Answer (score 1):

Porting [Traveller](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/users/16118/traveller)'s answer from the comments:

> Student visas are assessed on different criteria to visits. The frequency and length of your previous visits should not typically make any difference, unless you overstayed or otherwise breached UK immigration rules.

Comment: I did overstay in 2019 for a month due to covid as no flight. I did inform home office. Do I need to clarify this issue

Comment: Most definitely you will need to clarify that. That will also perhaps bring a bit more scrutiny to your previous 180 day stays, so be ready for that.

Comment: So it’s better not to apply the student visa as I might get ban?

Comment: It is highly unlikely you will 'get a ban' if your overstay was due to restrictions on travel due to the pandemic. But you may have to demonstrate that point. The only link I could find regarding this is [here](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/coronavirus-covid-19-advice-for-uk-visa-applicants-and-temporary-uk-residents). It is curious that your overstay was in 2019, before any real restrictions had taken place. I'm not sure how the Home Office will accept 'no flights' for discretion. You might want to contact an immigration attorney who can research the matter in greater depth.

Comment: Should I provide email from home office inside the application and provide extra note on the extra column towards the end. Kindly advice. I came from dec 2019 - July 2020

Comment: @Mayra, What email? What does it say? Is it in response to a query you made?

Comment: Yes email I received after I request for exceptional. Should I provide on the extra box comment.

Comment: I should provide 3 recent visit to uk. So should I put 2022,2020,2018? Or do I need to put 2016 I came for study

Comment: @Mayra, Did they grant you exceptional grounds? If they ask for 3, you only have to provide 3. But I would include the 2016 stay as well just because it provides extra evidence that you can/will come for study and leave again all within the rules. They ofcourse can disregard that at their discretion. But I don't think it will hurt at all.